# Create Fix version via Rest Api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am running JIRA(7.2) on my server. Is it possible create a new Fix Version within a project, via JIRA REST API? I googled a bit and tried it myself, but got an error  (403).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this Endpoint to create your Version in JIRA: https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.2.0/#api/2/version-createVersion

Error 403 indicates, that the user which is issueing the REST call, may not have the appropriate permission to create a new version.